# Why are bees "committing suicide" in my house?

Tags: entomology, bees

There is a beehive about 500-1000 meters away from my house.
During the last years, almost every day, one or more bees enter from the window, "dance" for an hour or two, and then drop dead on the floor. Some more details:

- The bees may come in every hour of the day, but most of them come just before sunrise. This morning about 20 of them came in; now they are all dead on the floor near the window:

[image]

- Often, the bees prefer to make their "dance" near the lamp. But this is not always the case.
- They usually do not sting me; I was stung only twice, the bee died immediately afterwards, I took the sting out with tweezers, and it did not hurt too much.
- I did not use pesticides or any other stuff that could kill the bees.

Why are they doing this? How can I stop them from coming?

I read that [bees are disappearing](https://news.cnrs.fr/articles/why-bees-are-disappearing); maybe it's because they all come to my house to die? :-)

Comment: How can we possibly know?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! This is probably not an answerable question on this site since there could be many different reasons. To get an answer try contacting a local agricultural extension agent or entomology department and see whether you can get someone local interested to check for toxins and pathogens. ——— Please take the time to take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Comment: Abnormal behavior could be explained by use of pesticides, such as neonicotinoids. You may not be using pesticides, but agricultural companies around your place of residence may be using them. Hard to say for sure in the regulatory vacuum we live in, where our environment is concerned. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colony_collapse_disorder

Comment: @tyersome thanks for the welcome. I thought that maybe this phoenomenon has been observed in other places too, so maybe there is some research about it.

Comment: As @AlexReynolds indicated bee loss has been linked to [neonicotinoids](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-017-10489-6) (a class of pesticides often used as a seed treatment), but many pesticides and [pathogens](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/een.12434) can have neurological effects.  Consequently, I wouldn't believe any diagnosis made that didn't involve inspection for parasites and a toxicological workup ... Also getting someone local involved could result in the problem being solved!

Comment: @tyersome thanks! Following your advice I contacted the bee department in the ministry of agriculture in my country. I hope they will have a solution.

Comment: It's possible that there's something confusing them about the light. Does the window face the rising sun?  I've read that at twilight, bees get confused by nearby lights; maybe this happens at dawn as well. In one particular case, a beekeeper's porch light. The beekeeper moved the hive and it helped. Not a terribly helpful comment, but if the window does, in fact, face the rising sun, that might have something to do with it. Try having the hive moved.

Comment: Kind of a possibility: https://www.beebestinc.com/are-bees-attracted-to-light/

Comment: @David - Just because you don't know doesn't mean no one can know. forestecologist might know; a bee keeper might know; who knows who might kniow, but someone might. You should be less dismissive.

Comment: @anongoodnurse — No. The question relates to a particular circumstance, rather than a generality —  **my** house. How can anyone know the particulars of this, or even if the poster’s observations are reliable?

Comment: @anongoodnurse your guess was correct - my window does indeed face the rising sun. And the link you gave indeed describes a situation very similar to mine. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After years of struggling with the bees, I finally found a solution. I put in my window a lot of pots with various flowers, including some vegetable plants with flowers. Now, instead of entering my house, the bees go to the flowers.

As a bonus, I get wonderful scents and some fresh cucumbers - pollinated by the bees. I have learned that bees are not a nuisance - they are an asset!

Comment: Don't forget to mark your answer as best answer.

Comment: Fragrances inside your house were probably attracting them then. I just use nets to keep out lots of curious insects. Bees and wasps, for no discernible reasons, sometimes investigate the nets pretty thoroughly... almost certainly looking for a way in, either to nest or who knows what.

Comment: Also, based on your location: in arid/desert areas bee colonies send out more scouts.

Comment: By the way, bees can see UV and of all the frequencies this is the most attractive to them https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-020-64782-y. So it's possible the bulbs you were using, e.g. if CFL, were attracting them.

Answer (score 2):

I found another solution, for a season when the flowers on the window are insufficient. I have noticed that bees are attracted to my light bulbs, especially in the early morning when it is dark outside. I have also read that [bees cannot see red light](https://news.ncsu.edu/2011/07/wms-what-bees-see/) - it is beyond their visibility spectrum.

So, I bought some RGB bulbs - bulbs with a remote control for changing colors. These are [surprisingly cheap](https://www.aliexpress.com/wholesale?SearchText=rgb%20bulb). Now, whenever the bees approach, I switch the light to red, and they go away.